# How to use Batch Dir Command for a website folder

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I want to do something like this:

```
 Dir http://www.mysite.com/
```

Is it possible? 
How to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to have FTP access to the site. Do you? If not, you'll have to use `wget` or `curl`. Google for them.

Comment: I don't have ftp access.